# What's the difference between these different import statements for the Cloud Datastore in Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm reading about how to use the Datastore and have come across different import statements in Google's own guides:

`import “google.golang.org/appengine/datastore”`

^ from “Getting started with the Google Cloud Datastore API” (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial)

`import “appengine/datastore”`

^ from “Creating a Guestbook Application” (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/getting-started/creating-guestbook), older version of code

`import “cloud.google.com/go/datastore”`

^ from “Creating a Guestbook Application”, more recent code.

What's the difference between these statements? What's the "standard" way to import the datastore package, if any?